# Putting multiple numbers from an input into one list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to put multiple interest rates from one input into a list. I'm assuming just putting a comma between them wont separate them into different variables in the list? Is there a way I can get them all into a list in one input or do i need to run the input multiple times and add one each time?

```
interest_rates_list = []


while True:
    investment = input("Please enter the amount to be invested ")
    periods = input("Please enter the number of periods for investment maturity ")
    if int(periods) < 0:
        break
    interest_rates = input("Please enter the interest rate for each period ")
    interest_rates_list.append(interest_rates)
```

Comment: There are a few options available. To give a really solid answer, it would help to have some example inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 3):

If you input is something like:

```
4 5 12 8 42
```

then you can simply split it up by space and assign to `values` list:

```
values = input().split()
```

If your input something like `4,5,12`, then you need to use `split(',')`.

Answer (score 1):

You can `split` the `input string` into several `string` and then convert it to `float`. This can be done in one line.

```py
interest_rates = list(map(float, interest_rates.split(",")))
```

Here I go a step further, your next move will be to calculate some return based on interest rates, and so you will need float/integer to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The python string function split can accept a delimiter character and split the input string into a list of values delimited by that character.

```
interest_rates = input("Please enter the interest rate for each period ")
interest_rates_list = interest_rates.split(",")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take the input, you can convert it to a string by using:

```
str(interest_rates)
```

Let this be variable A
So, `A = str(interest_rates)`

Now, to seperate each entry of the interest rates, we do:

```
interest_rates_list = A.split(' ')
```

This function literally splits the string at all spaces and returns a list of all the broken pieces.

NOTE: if you do `A.split(*any string or character*)` it'll split at the mentioned character. Could be ',' or ';' or ':', etc.

Now you can iter over the newly formed list and convert all the numbers stored as string to ints or floats by doing

```
for i in interest _rates_list:
    i = float(i) #or int(i) based on your requirement
```